# AD user can't login to laptop

Tags: windows-10, login, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I have created a home lab environment to practice Active Directory, I have managed to set the domain controller up, ad it seems to be working.

However, I added a laptop to the domain, and I was able to login with different ad user profiles and it all seemed to work.

Now for some reason I can't login to the laptop with any of the previously used profiles, I keep getting "Can't logon because the logon method you are using is not allowed on this computer"?

Thanks.

Comment: Login with a local admin account and check the event log for more details.

Comment: Anything in particluar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the user(s) or groups they are a part of, have the logon locally permission.

This is done by checking group policy and modifying it accordingly. You may have accidentally modified the related policies and have prevented your users from logging on.

The policy can be set both locally on the PC (Using `gpedit.msc`) or pushed to the workstation from the server using group policy management console.

You will find the policies you need in `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment`

Look for:

- Allow logon locally
- Deny logon locally

By default, deny should be empty. Allow should contain `Authenticated users`. Check your `Default Domain Policy` first, to see if it has been changed.

Apply your policy changes to the workstation by logging on with a local user account and running the `gpupdate /force` command or by rebooting the computer and waiting a few minutes for it to update its policy.